# format splunk query by renaming search elements

Tags: splunk

I could use a little help with a splunk query I’m trying to use.

This query works fine for gathering the info I need:

```
index=prd_aws_billing (source="/*2017-12.csv") LinkedAccountId="1234567810" OR LinkedAccountId="123456789" ProductName="Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud" | stats sum(UnBlendedCost) AS Cost by ResourceId,UsageType,user_Name,user_Engagement
```

However I’d like to refine that a bit. I’d like to represent user_Engagement as just Engagement and  user_Name as “Resource Name”.

I tried using AS to change the output, like I did to change UnBlendedCost to just “Cost”. But when I do that it kills my query, and nothing is returned. For instance if I do either:

```
index=prd_aws_billing (source="/*2017-12.csv") LinkedAccountId="123456789" OR LinkedAccountId="1234567810" ProductName="Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud" | stats sum(UnBlendedCost) AS Cost by ResourceId AS “Resource Name”,UsageType,user_Name,user_Engagement AS “Engagement”
```

Or

```
index=prd_aws_billing (source="/*2017-12.csv") LinkedAccountId="123456789" OR LinkedAccountId="1234567819" ProductName="Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud" ResourceID AS “Resource Name” user_Engagement AS “Engagement” | stats sum(UnBlendedCost) AS Cost by ResourceId AS “Resource Name”,UsageType,user_Name,user_Engagement AS “Engagement”
```

The query dies, and no info is returned. How can I reformat the search elements listed after the 'by' clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the |rename command.  You can only use AS to rename the fields that are being transformed in a |stats.

```
index=prd_aws_billing (source="/*2017-12.csv") LinkedAccountId="1234567810" OR LinkedAccountId="123456789" ProductName="Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud" 
| stats sum(UnBlendedCost) AS Cost by ResourceId,UsageType,user_Name,user_Engagement
| rename user_Name as "Resource Name" user_Engagement as Engagement
```